# Passing one random value to two super arguments

Tags: class, inheritance, dart, super

Basically I want to pass a random argument twice to a parent class.

Consider the following example:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class A {
  double a;
  double b;

  A(this.a, this.b) {
    if (a != b) {
      print('Error');
    } else {
      print('Alright');
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  B() : super(math.Random().nextDouble(), math.Random().nextDouble());
}

main() {
  B();
}
```

Here is the only solution I can come up with, but this feels so hacky... I hope someone else could provide me with a better one.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class A {
  double a;
  double b;

  A(this.a, this.b) {
    if (a != b) {
      print('Error');
    } else {
      print('Alright');
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static List<double> _c = [0];
  bool uselessBool;

  B() : uselessBool = random(),
        super(_c[0], _c[0]);

  static bool random() {
    _c[0] = math.Random().nextDouble();
    return true;
  }
}

main() {
  B();
}
```

What I which could exist would be something like this (As you would do in python for example):

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class A {
  double a;
  double b;

  A(this.a, this.b) {
    if (a != b) {
      print('Error');
    } else {
      print('Alright');
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {

  B() {
    var c = math.Random().nextDouble();
    super(c, c);
  }
}

main() {
  B();
}
```

Comment: I *think* the best method would be to create a single argument constructor for A.

Comment: I didn't create the A class. Well in this example I did but it's a simplification of a greater problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a hidden constructor by making a named constructor starting with `_`. By doing that we can create the following example which does what you want:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class A {
  double a;
  double b;

  A(this.a, this.b) {
    if (a != b) {
      print('Error');
    } else {
      print('Alright');
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  B() : this._(math.Random().nextDouble());
  B._(double value) : super(value, value);
}

void main() {
  B();
}
```

If you want more complicated logic you can also take a look at factory constructors which basically works as static methods but must return an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. Still a bit weird with my 20+ parent class but better than what I proposed. I'll have a look at factory too. Thanks again

Comment: If you have 20+ parent classes which have this pattern I will suggest you look into how you maybe can change the constructor of `A` so it works better for you. You can e.g. define A to be `A(double value) : a = value, b = value` and by doing this reuse the parameter to define multiple variables in your class.

Comment: I meant 20+ arguments in the parent class sorry. And I can't really change the A class since it's a built in class (I could but it would make the all thing confusing for future maintainers)

Comment: Ok, I don't know your problem in full details so I can't say if there are a better solution for you. :)

Comment: I know your answer is perfect in the context of my question so thanks :)